# NLTK was unable to find stanford-parser\.jar! Set the CLASSPATH environment variable

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

the nltk.parse.stanford in nltk3.2.5.

```
from nltk.parse.stanford import *

# CoreNLPServer = CoreNLPServer(path_to_jar="/home/fonttian/NLP/stanford/")

# dep_parser=StanfordDependencyParser(model_path="/home/fonttian/NLP/stanford/stanford-chinese-corenlp-2017-06-09-models/edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/chinesePCFG.ser.gz")
```

====>

```
dep_parser=StanfordDependencyParser(model_path="edu/stanford/nlp/models
```

/lexparser/chinesePCFG.ser.gz")
      File "/home/fonttian/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/nltk/parse/stanford.py", line 52, in **init**
        key=lambda model_path: os.path.dirname(model_path)
      File "/home/fonttian/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/nltk/internals.py", line 716, in find_jar_iter
        raise LookupError('\n\n%s\n%s\n%s' % (div, msg, div))
    LookupError:

```
============================
  NLTK was unable to find stanford-parser\.jar! Set the CLASSPATH
  environment variable.

  For more information, on stanford-parser\.jar, see:
    <https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml>
===============================
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/46734119/610569

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the jars for the Stanford parser and the models to your CLASSPATH:

1. download Stanford CoreNLP 3.8.0 (and the Chinese models jar) available here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html
2. place the Chinese models jar in the Stanford CoreNLP folder
3. add this to your Python:

   ```
   os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = "/path/to/stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09/*"
   ```

I think that should fix your issue.

Comment: I do it   "import os
os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = "fonttian/home/NLP/stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09/*"

Comment: but nothing happened,"  NLTK was unable to find stanford-parser\.jar! Set the CLASSPATH
  environment variable.

  For more information, on stanford-parser\.jar, see:
    <https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml>

Comment: In fact,I cannot find the stanford-parser\.jar in "stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09"

Comment: when i use '2015',error:错误: 找不到或无法加载主类 edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser

Comment: from nltk.parse.stanford import *
import os
os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = "/home/fonttian/NLP/stanford-2015/*"

dep_parser=StanfordDependencyParser('/home/fonttian/NLP/stanford-2015/models/chinese-distsim.tagger',"/home/fonttian/NLP/stanford-2015/stanford-parser.jar")
dep_parser.raw_parse("自然语言处理的测试句子")

Comment: at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar.<clinit>(ParserGrammar.java:46)
  File "/home/fonttian/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/parse/stanford.py", line 134, in raw_parse
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 ... 1 more

Comment: You should try using the Stanford Parser 3.8.0 distribution which can be found here: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.html (scroll down towards bottom)...use the folder you download from there it will contain the jars

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp here's a quick guide to documentation as of NLTK v3.2.5. It would be even cleaner in NLTK v3.2.6 (next version) Hopefully that'll ease the users' pain =)

Answer (score 0):

Download them from:

stanford/stanford-parser.jar.zip

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadstanfordparserjar.htm

stanford-parser-3.5.2-models.jar

http://central.maven.org/maven2/edu/stanford/nlp/stanford-parser/3.5.2/

And point the file paths in code.