# NLTK Stanford Segmentor, how to set CLASSPATH

Tags: java, python, classpath, nltk, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to use the Stanford Segementer bit from the NLTK Tokenize package. However, I run into issues just trying to use the basic test set. Running the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from nltk.tokenize.stanford_segmenter import StanfordSegmenter
seg = StanfordSegmenter()
seg.default_config('zh')
sent = u'这是斯坦福中文分词器测试'
print(seg.segment(sent))
```

Results in this error: 
[image: Error]

I got as far as to add...

```
import os
javapath = "C:/Users/User/Folder/stanford-segmenter-2017-06-09/*"
os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = javapath
```

...to the front of my code, but that didn't seem to help.

How do I get the segmentor to run properly?

Comment: The `CLASSPATH` should be a directory (or several), not a file glob. Change it to `"C:/Users/User/Folder/stanford-segmenter-2017-06-09"` and see if that helps. But there might be other issues, I don't know.

Comment: That didn't seem to help, thank you though. I'm probably trying to do too much without understanding how things are set up. For now, I'll look into using a different program or package. Apparently "Jieba" is another Python alternative, no need to call in Java.

Comment: Suit yourself. But have you looked at [Installing Third Party Software](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki/Installing-Third-Party-Software) on the nltk's github site? (I've no idea why this page doesn't come up in the nltk's FAQ page...)

Comment: RAWR.... hahaha... We really want to get rid of this `StanfordSegmenter` thing, hopefully in the next version, it will disappear...

Comment: @alexis But I agree, we need to document these properly!

Comment: @alvas, never mind the segmenter: Can you see to it that there's an item in the [nltk FAQ](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki/FAQ) that points to the "Installing Third Party Software" page? This is important.

Comment: It wouldn't be a bad idea to put some other _real_ frequently asked questions on the FAQ, too. You know what they are...

Comment: Getting to the 3rd party on FAQ right away!!

Comment: It could be better but here's a start: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions-(Stackoverflow-Edition)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the 3rd party install info. I've decided to go with the other package for now, but will leave this post up as it's could help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: This solution would **only work for**:

- NLTK v3.2.5 (v3.2.6 would have an even simpler interface)
- Stanford CoreNLP (version >= 2016-10-31)

---

First you have to get Java 8 properly installed first and if Stanford CoreNLP works on command line, the Stanford CoreNLP API in NLTK v3.2.5 is as follows.

**Note:** You have to start the CoreNLP server in terminal **BEFORE** using the new CoreNLP API in NLTK.

## English

In terminal:

```
wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31.zip
unzip stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31.zip && cd stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31

java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer \
-preload tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse,depparse \
-status_port 9000 -port 9000 -timeout 15000
```

In Python:

```
>>> from nltk.tag.stanford import CoreNLPPOSTagger, CoreNLPNERTagger
>>> stpos, stner = CoreNLPPOSTagger(), CoreNLPNERTagger()
>>> stpos.tag('What is the airspeed of an unladen swallow ?'.split())
[(u'What', u'WP'), (u'is', u'VBZ'), (u'the', u'DT'), (u'airspeed', u'NN'), (u'of', u'IN'), (u'an', u'DT'), (u'unladen', u'JJ'), (u'swallow', u'VB'), (u'?', u'.')]
>>> stner.tag('Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split())
[(u'Rami', u'PERSON'), (u'Eid', u'PERSON'), (u'is', u'O'), (u'studying', u'O'), (u'at', u'O'), (u'Stony', u'ORGANIZATION'), (u'Brook', u'ORGANIZATION'), (u'University', u'ORGANIZATION'), (u'in', u'O'), (u'NY', u'O')]
```

## Chinese

In terminal:

```
wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31.zip
unzip stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31.zip && cd stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31
wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-chinese-corenlp-2016-10-31-models.jar
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties 

java -Xmx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer \
-serverProperties StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties \
-preload tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse \
-status_port 9001  -port 9001 -timeout 15000
```

In Python

```
>>> from nltk.tag.stanford import CoreNLPPOSTagger, CoreNLPNERTagger
>>> from nltk.tokenize.stanford import CoreNLPTokenizer
>>> stpos, stner = CoreNLPPOSTagger('http://localhost:9001'), CoreNLPNERTagger('http://localhost:9001')
>>> sttok = CoreNLPTokenizer('http://localhost:9001')

>>> sttok.tokenize(u'我家没有电脑。')
['我家', '没有', '电脑', '。']

# Without segmentation (input to`raw_string_parse()` is a list of single char strings)
>>> stpos.tag(u'我家没有电脑。')
[('我', 'PN'), ('家', 'NN'), ('没', 'AD'), ('有', 'VV'), ('电', 'NN'), ('脑', 'NN'), ('。', 'PU')]
# With segmentation
>>> stpos.tag(sttok.tokenize(u'我家没有电脑。'))
[('我家', 'NN'), ('没有', 'VE'), ('电脑', 'NN'), ('。', 'PU')]

# Without segmentation (input to`raw_string_parse()` is a list of single char strings)
>>> stner.tag(u'奥巴马与迈克尔·杰克逊一起去杂货店购物。')
[('奥', 'GPE'), ('巴', 'GPE'), ('马', 'GPE'), ('与', 'O'), ('迈', 'O'), ('克', 'PERSON'), ('尔', 'PERSON'), ('·', 'O'), ('杰', 'O'), ('克', 'O'), ('逊', 'O'), ('一', 'NUMBER'), ('起', 'O'), ('去', 'O'), ('杂', 'O'), ('货', 'O'), ('店', 'O'), ('购', 'O'), ('物', 'O'), ('。', 'O')]
# With segmentation
>>> stner.tag(sttok.tokenize(u'奥巴马与迈克尔·杰克逊一起去杂货店购物。'))
[('奥巴马', 'PERSON'), ('与', 'O'), ('迈克尔·杰克逊', 'PERSON'), ('一起', 'O'), ('去', 'O'), ('杂货店', 'O'), ('购物', 'O'), ('。', 'O')]
```

## German

In terminal:

```
wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31.zip
unzip stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31.zip && cd stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31

wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-german-corenlp-2016-10-31-models.jar
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP-german.properties

java -Xmx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer \
-serverProperties StanfordCoreNLP-german.properties \
-preload tokenize,ssplit,pos,ner,parse \
-status_port 9002  -port 9002 -timeout 15000
```

In Python:

```
>>> from nltk.tag.stanford import CoreNLPPOSTagger, CoreNLPNERTagger
>>> stpos, stner = CoreNLPPOSTagger('http://localhost:9002'), CoreNLPNERTagger('http://localhost:9002')

>>> stpos.tag('Ich bin schwanger'.split())
[('Ich', 'PPER'), ('bin', 'VAFIN'), ('schwanger', 'ADJD')]

>>> stner.tag('Donald Trump besuchte Angela Merkel in Berlin.'.split())
[('Donald', 'I-PER'), ('Trump', 'I-PER'), ('besuchte', 'O'), ('Angela', 'I-PER'), ('Merkel', 'I-PER'), ('in', 'O'), ('Berlin', 'I-LOC'), ('.', 'O')]
```

## Spanish

In terminal:

```
wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31.zip
unzip stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31.zip && cd stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31

wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-spanish-corenlp-2016-10-31-models.jar
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP-spanish.properties

java -Xmx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer \
-serverProperties StanfordCoreNLP-spanish.properties \
-preload tokenize,ssplit,pos,ner,parse \
-status_port 9003  -port 9003 -timeout 15000
```

In Python:

```
>>> from nltk.tag.stanford import CoreNLPPOSTagger, CoreNLPNERTagger
>>> stpos, stner = CoreNLPPOSTagger('http://localhost:9003'), CoreNLPNERTagger('http://localhost:9003')

>>> stner.tag(u'Barack Obama salió con Michael Jackson .'.split())
[(u'Barack', u'PERS'), (u'Obama', u'PERS'), (u'sali\xf3', u'O'), (u'con', u'O'), (u'Michael', u'PERS'), (u'Jackson', u'PERS'), (u'.', u'O')]

>>> stpos.tag(u'Barack Obama salió con Michael Jackson .'.split())
[(u'Barack', u'np00000'), (u'Obama', u'np00000'), (u'sali\xf3', u'vmis000'), (u'con', u'sp000'), (u'Michael', u'np00000'), (u'Jackson', u'np00000'), (u'.', u'fp')]
```

## French

In terminal:

```
wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31.zip
unzip stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31.zip && cd stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31

wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-french-corenlp-2016-10-31-models.jar
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP-french.properties

java -Xmx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer \
-serverProperties StanfordCoreNLP-french.properties \
-preload tokenize,ssplit,pos,parse \
-status_port 9004  -port 9004 -timeout 15000
```

In Python:

```
>>> from nltk.tag.stanford import CoreNLPPOSTagger
>>> stpos = CoreNLPPOSTagger('http://localhost:9004')
>>> stpos.tag('Je suis enceinte'.split())
[(u'Je', u'CLS'), (u'suis', u'V'), (u'enceinte', u'NC')]
```

## Arabic

In terminal:

```
wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31.zip
unzip stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31.zip && cd stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31

wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-arabic-corenlp-2016-10-31-models.jar
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP-arabic.properties

java -Xmx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer \
-serverProperties StanfordCoreNLP-french.properties \
-preload tokenize,ssplit,pos,parse \
-status_port 9005  -port 9005 -timeout 15000
```

In Python:

```
>>> from nltk.tag.stanford import CoreNLPPOSTagger
>>> from nltk.tokenize.stanford import CoreNLPTokenizer
>>> sttok = CoreNLPTokenizer('http://localhost:9005')
>>> stpos = CoreNLPPOSTagger('http://localhost:9005')
>>> text = u'انا حامل'
>>> stpos.tag(sttok.tokenize(text))
[('انا', 'DET'), ('حامل', 'NC')]
```